# Working with WebTables with Horizontal Scrollbar in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar

An WebTable is embedded in the WebPage to be automated. It has lot of fields and hence has it's own horizontal scrollbar (The scrollbar is specific to the WebTable and not to the whole WebPage). When I try to interact/click the webelements currently hidden because of the scrollbar, it results in NoSuchElementException/ElementNotVisibleException.

Please let me know how to handle/Scroll the horizontal scrollbar of the WebTable, making any specified element visible.

Comment: Is the webtable in an iFrame?  If it is, you will need to tell the driver to switch its focus to it in order to scroll/get to the elements in it.  I am currently en route to work and will try to give a better explanation once I am at my desk.

Comment: as @Brian has stated - when you say "is embedded", do you mean via `<embed>` tag? or a `<frame>`?

Comment: @Brian ,sircapsalot Sorry for using the word embedded. The table under question is not within any <embed> or <frame> tags. It's just a WebTable with it's own horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the table and post the mark-up that renders it to your original post, please?  Also, can you see it in the DOM when the page loads or is it only loaded when needed?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the code below. This code has worked for me.

```
WebElement elment = driver.findElemen(By.id("table_header"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```